# Web Site pings different ip depending on if I ping from server or local machine

Tags: iis, firewall, web-hosting

I have a web app hosted on a server that was recently moved to a new location and has a new ip address associated with it. I am not well versed in networking or server administration so any help is appreciated.

My web apps cannot be accessed at all, I host them on IIS and have messed around with the ip addresses a little bit. I tried to point the domain to the new public ip address on godaddy. com. I tried changing the Forward Lookup Zones ip addresses on DNS Manager. But no luck.

The problem is, I ping the web app from my local machine `ping mydomainname.com` and get the new ip address of the server, when I ping the site from the SQL Server I get the old ip address.

I have looked at Windows Firewall Rules on the server and notice that there is a rule:

> Forward 443 to Public
>
> Forward 80 to Public

Also when I run:

```
nslookup
>set type=A
>mydomainname.com
```

It shows the new ip address when ran on the server, but not the correct one when ran from my local machine.

The sites are run on Port 443 and Port 80. I am wondering if I should remove that rule or not? Any help is appreciated.

Also I have been trying at this for a few days now, I only have `TTL` of 10 minutes, and I've been clearing my cache on my local machine regularly with `ipconfig /flushdns`.

Answer (score 0):

DNS Records to have a TTL - a Time To Live in seconds. So on the machine(s) where you get the old IP address, the record is in some kind of cache. Just to spice things up, there might also be a cache on an intermediate server that is configured between your host and the root DNS provider for your domain.

On windows, simply call `ipconfig /flushdns`, on other systems it depends on your DNS resolver. Try [this howto](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-flush-dns-cache) or google for "clear DNS cache *yourOS*".

The firewall has nothing to do with IP resolution, so disabling anything there should not help you anyways.

Comment: I will edit my question with the details, but I worked on this last week and today. My TTL is 10 minutes and I've been running clearing the dns cache, and nothing has worked.

Comment: I've tried checking A records too, thinking that may have something to do with it. But I can't seem to find the problem. Also I will point out that the sites do come up on my server but not anywhere else.

Comment: Does your `nsloopup` call - first 2 lines - point to an external or internal DNS server? You might have one internally that has a separate domain config. You could try changing the DNS server to `1.1.1.1` or `8.8.8.8` to check if this could help you out. IP resolution **must** be a DNS problem...

Comment: It is an internal server is 'localhost` and address is '127.x.x.x' when ran on my server. I will look into changing the dns server in the mean time.

Comment: The "forward lookup zone" is exactly what causes your problem in here. The reverse one should cause no harm. I would suggest that at first, you simply try changing the DNS on the failing hosts network interface...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll look into it but I'm not the server admin and I've only really hosted web apps through cloud services, so this is new to me.

Comment: If you have any chance, try to watch what the admin is doing and keep asking questions. It'll really help you out later. DNS is a freaky thing at first... ;)

Comment: Okay I've made progress. In my C:\Winodws\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file I added 
`xx.xx.xx.xx mydomainname.com` and it at leasts pulls up on my local computer now.

Comment: hosts file always overrules everything else. But there is a problem with name resolutions anyways that should be addressed!

Comment: Should I try to delete the entries in forward lookup zones and reenter them? Because They were there before the server was moved, I simply edited them with the new ip

Comment: You should configure the DNS in a way that it gets the DNS records from your **leading DNS server**. If there is no real need for a local DNS server, disable it.